# DataGridView minimum number of decimal places

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I want to format the decimal places displayed and captured in a DataGridView, I have a minimum number of decimal places and a maximum number of decimal places. For example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. 1) please don't post code as images into your question. [Here are the reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5174469). 2) Your post is missing a question. Please state the nature of your problem and try to formulate a question. 3) post only the necessary code to reproduce your problem. People usually don't have much time to read pages over pages of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the DefaultCellStyle.Format property of the desired column.

```cs
dataGridView1.Columns[indexOfColumn].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
```

The numeric value after the 'N' will determine how many decimal places will be displayed at all time.

Read the following MSDN article for more details about the formatting types:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types